# Confused with UL & Flex CSS, 2 Rowws, 2 Columns, total 4 Items

Tags: html, css, wordpress, flexbox, related-posts

I am trying to style my WordPress Posts into 2 wide and 2 rows.

I created Frankenstein!

How can I get this to be like this image.

[image]

[Click me for Dev Website](http://svcta.lainternet.biz/directory/grand-vista-hotel/stay/)

PHP/HTML

```
    <ul class="svcta_listing_related_posts_ul">
    <li class="svcta_listing_related_posts_li">
        <?php foreach( $posts as $post): ?>
        <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('listing_post_thumbnail'); ?> 
            <div class="svcta_listing_related_posts_link"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
    </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.svcta_listing_related_posts_ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.svcta_listing_related_posts_li {
margin-right: 75px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this using css grid. check code snippet below

```css
.svcta_listing_related_posts_ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}

.svcta_listing_related_posts_li {
  margin-right: 75px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="svcta_listing_related_posts_ul">
  <li class="svcta_listing_related_posts_li">
    <?php foreach( $posts as $post): ?>
    <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('listing_post_thumbnail'); ?>
    <div class="svcta_listing_related_posts_link">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?>test
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
 <li class="svcta_listing_related_posts_li">
    <?php foreach( $posts as $post): ?>
    <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('listing_post_thumbnail'); ?>
    <div class="svcta_listing_related_posts_link">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?>test
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
 <li class="svcta_listing_related_posts_li">
    <?php foreach( $posts as $post): ?>
    <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('listing_post_thumbnail'); ?>
    <div class="svcta_listing_related_posts_link">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?>test
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
 <li class="svcta_listing_related_posts_li">
    <?php foreach( $posts as $post): ?>
    <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('listing_post_thumbnail'); ?>
    <div class="svcta_listing_related_posts_link">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?>test
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>

  <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

below highlighted part should be wrap in li 
[image]

Comment: I moved my comment to an answer as I couldn't figure out how to format the code into a code box.

Comment: please wrap `img` and  div `<div class="svcta_listing_related_posts_link">` in li and check

Comment: also check attached image

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="svcta_listing_related_posts_ul">
  <?php foreach( $posts as $post): ?>
    <li class="svcta_listing_related_posts_li">
      <?php
        setup_postdata($post);
        the_post_thumbnail('listing_post_thumbnail');
      ?> 
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
      </a>
    </li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>

.svcta_listing_related_posts_ul {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: -75px 0 0 0;
}
.svcta_listing_related_posts_li {
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 37.5px);
  padding: 75px 0 0 0;
}
```

[image]

I will avoid to put div inside li

### EDIT

If you want now 4 images on the same line it'll be a little bit different, here's the complete code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    .svcta_listing_related_posts_ul,
    .svcta_listing_related_posts_ul * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .svcta_listing_related_posts_ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 10px;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      align-items: flex-start;
      justify-content: space-between;
      margin: -10px 0 0 10px;
    }
    .svcta_listing_related_posts_li {
      flex-basis: 25%;
      max-width: 250px;
      padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
    }

    .svcta_listing_related_posts_li img {
      max-width: 100%;
    }

    .svcta_listing_related_posts_li a,
    .svcta_listing_related_posts_li img {
      display: block;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
      .svcta_listing_related_posts_li {
        flex-basis: 50%;
        max-width: none;
      }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      .svcta_listing_related_posts_li {
        flex-basis: 100%;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .svcta_listing_related_posts_li img {
        margin: auto;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="svcta_listing_related_posts_ul">
    <li class="svcta_listing_related_posts_li">
      <img src="http://svcta.lainternet.biz/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/hotel_room_wedding_romance-200x200.jpg" class="attachment-listing_post_thumbnail size-listing_post_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="Hotel Room Wedding Romance" width="200" height="200"> 
      <a href="http://svcta.lainternet.biz/3-rehearsal-dinner-ideas-in-simi-valley/">
        3 Rehearsal Dinner Ideas in Simi Valley      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="svcta_listing_related_posts_li">
      <img src="http://svcta.lainternet.biz/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/hotel_room_wedding_romance-200x200.jpg" class="attachment-listing_post_thumbnail size-listing_post_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="Hotel Room Wedding Romance" width="200" height="200"> 
      <a href="http://svcta.lainternet.biz/3-things-you-need-to-know-before-booking-your-room/">
        3 Things you Need to Know Before Booking Your Room      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="svcta_listing_related_posts_li">
      <img src="http://svcta.lainternet.biz/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Wood_Ranch_Feature_500x360-200x200.jpg" class="attachment-listing_post_thumbnail size-listing_post_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="Wood Ranch Feature 500x360" width="200" height="200"> 
      <a href="http://svcta.lainternet.biz/stay-in-simi-valley-spend-the-day-outdoors/">
      Stay In Simi Valley &amp; Spend The Day Outdoors      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="svcta_listing_related_posts_li">
      <img src="http://svcta.lainternet.biz/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Gallery_Bestwestern_Wedding_500x400-200x200.jpg" class="attachment-listing_post_thumbnail size-listing_post_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="Gallery Bestwestern Wedding 500x400" width="200" height="200"> 
      <a href="http://svcta.lainternet.biz/stay-in-simi-wedding-guide/">
        Stay in Simi Wedding Guide      </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

save it to a .html file to see how it works. I didn't put it on a snippet because you have to see the result by resizing it.

Comment: Thanks again for the help.  I had a minor change and now need to do 4 wide.  I still need it to wrap on mobile so I think the code set will be the same or similar.

Comment: I am now using

    <ul class="svcta_listing_related_posts_ul">
      <?php foreach( $posts as $post): ?>
        <li class="svcta_listing_related_posts_li">
          <?php
            setup_postdata($post);
            the_post_thumbnail('listing_post_thumbnail');
          ?> 
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
          </a>
        </li>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>

Comment: .svcta_listing_related_posts_ul {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: -75px 0 0 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.svcta_listing_related_posts_li {
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 37.5px);
  padding: 75px 0 0 0;
}

Comment: I'm posting the code below, I am struggling to format it in the comments.

Comment: I updated my answer, on the bottom of the image, under EDIT title. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) how to format comments

Comment: Awesome!!!  That did exactly what I needed.  Thanks for pulling me out of the rabbit hole!

Comment: Can you mark the response as the good one if it satisfies you?

Comment: Thanks for the help with this system!  I have marked the correct answer.

Comment: Oh it's not my answer that you marked :-(. I don't know if it was a mistake, in any case I'm happy you found a solution